# Cannot start Jenkins with https

Tags: ssl, https, jenkins

Jenkins instance starts just fine if I run a start script with the following parameters:

```
HTTP_PORT=8180
AJP_PORT=8109
nohup nice $JAVA -jar $WAR --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT >> $LOG 2>> $ERR &
```

However, after enabling SSL with a self-signed certificate, as suggested here, https://github.com/hughperkins/howto-jenkins-ssl, passing the private key and certificate parameters, and disabling ajp and http ports as below, it fails to start.

```
HTTP_PORT=-1
AJP_PORT=-1
HTTPS_PORT=443
HTTPS_CERT=cert.pem
HTTPS_PK=key.pem

nohup nice $JAVA -jar $WAR --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --httpsPort=$HTTPS_PORT --httpsCertificiate=$HTTPS_CERT --httpsPrivateKey=$HTTPS_PK --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT >> $LOG 2>> $ERR &
```

It's probably to do with some kind of conflict among the different ports which I cannot see. Or, maybe the order of parameters passed to Winstone matters here?Please let me know if any information is missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not real solution, but... you can put proxy in front of jenkins and forwards requests to jenkins..

Comment: @alexus From the looks of it, it should be much easier than that - looks like I am missing something simple here...

Comment: I had same issue, and that's what I end up doing as I was not able to run it on anything other then standard port(

Comment: @alexus How did you end up going about it, is there a concise set of instructions that you can point me to?

Comment: It was a wrong port, I used 8443 and it worked.